# Repeating crap can beat the low quality filter

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

The "horrible-question" filter can apparently be bypassed by repeating the same crap over and over again.

For example,

[can someone find me example of sprite sheet animation java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201127/can-someone-find-me-example-of-sprite-sheet-animation-java-code)

> [image]

and [Expected ';' and Syntax error on comment lines along with Object expected errors WHAT PART OF THIS POST IS CODE?](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10183521/1),

> [image]

which also put in a gigantic pile of repetitive crap to bypass the filter.

Are there enough other instances to make a feature request that repeated-crap like this should be blocked? Or, are these just two isolated incidents?

Comment: I dunno about fixing this one, it IS an easy way to tell a terrible question.

Comment: feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz. feature req plz.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting phenomenon, but unless it becomes common, I don't think we have a problem.

The content filter is not meant to block *every* bad question (and it could never reach that goal). So if it matches most of it, that's fine.

And unless there's a concerted effort by all bad-question-writers to collect all possible ways to circumvent the filter, this is probably not a problem. Luckily such a concerted effort would require pretty much the skills that would make them better questions-writers, so that's unlikely.

Comment: It is at least somewhat common.  It tends to get quickly edited out (letting the users fully bypass the filter), so it's a little hard to find).

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed a number of questions which just repeat the exact question body 3 or 4 times to beat the filter.

It should be fairly simple to detect such questions.

(although users might then start tweaking each copy to try to get past, which would be harder to detect)

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16427514/1

Comment: I'm somewhat disappointed that this answer does not repeat.

Comment: Meh, this is where I say that I'm glad there are people in the system.  Just apply downvotes to such situations.