# Question for community moderators (10K) only

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I think we can all agree that **a lot** of questions on meta are about things that happened like a post deletion and stuff.

Let's take [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129587/repeating-crap-can-apparently-beat-the-content-filter) as example.

I don't have high reputation on meta and can't see deleted post. **But** I judge I've been around long enough to know how things work around here and I know why a question/answer should be deleted or not. It's obvious that this question is not about `undeleting` something so I don't think it should be for `10K+` users only.

What do I do when I come across a question like this where I can't access any of the provided examples (since I can't see deleted post)? I don't want the privilege to `Delete` or `Undelete` but I'd love to be able to *at least* see the post (read-only mode).

Could that be implemented in some way?
Are these posts reserved for community moderators only?
Another option could be to point out in the tags that the question is for community moderators only?

---

Edit:

I just realised someone posted the picture of the post in the body of the question so my question looks silly right now. But still it *almost never happens* so I still think it would be a good thing to support.

Comment: What can you do? Just obtain the privilege. And if it's really vital to a question, perhaps ask someone to include relevant details, should they be missing. And of course there is always [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10201127/edit).

Comment: @Bart if the *only* option is to wait until I have the tools, shouldn't these question be marked as Modertors Only so I can filter them ?

Comment: Meh, should be easy enough to identify them and move on. Spending less time on Meta is a good thing.

Comment: [It was me who posted the pictures](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/129587/4), and I don't have 10k either. I used the same trick @Bart has suggested.

Comment: Well unfortunately, I like it here on meta and so do you ! I just thought it could be a nice addition. Since a title like `Repeating crap can beat the low quality filter` doesn't **at any point** show that I will need 10K to participate. Also it's a nice question so I would love to participate ^_^

Comment: @Antony I didn't know about that thanks :)

Comment: Which is why screenshots should be included in the first place...

Comment: @Antony That only works if you have 2k on the site.

Comment: @Seth 500 will do (the retag privilege).

Comment: @Antony Are you sure? Maybe I'll find out someday... ;)

Comment: @Seth I am sure. I don't have 2k on meta, but I can view this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1/edit

Comment: @Antony And what is this work around ? How do I do it ?

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk Just look at the URLs

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk There is a post id for every question. Just type in `stackoverflow.com/posts/{id}/edit` and you are good to go.

Comment: Clearly the answer to your problem is to post a new meta question asking to see deleted posts with a link to the post you can't see.  This apparently has the effect of causing someone to go grab a screenshot of that post for you.  (This user is not responsible for any negative effects as a result of such a question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted means out of view for anyone less than 10K rep.

We delete answers which aren't answers, questions which aren't questions, or both which are spam or not constructive in any way. We shouldn't keep those kinds of questions and answers on the site, so we delete them.

I don't think we should keep these posts just because they're referenced on Meta - however, I don't think they should be deleted unless there's already a screenshot of it in the meta post.

Additionally, if the OP of a meta post thinks it is needed, then the OP can either flag or post a comment asking for a screenshot (if it hasn't happened already). I've personally done that a couple times, where the content of a deleted post was absolutely critical to the point of my post.

Comment: Yes screenshots should be mandatory. WHich is my read-only approach.

Comment: But... they're _deleted_. Deleted doesn't mean read-only, it means _gone_ (mostly).

Comment: Well isn't a screenshot a `read-only` version of the post .. ? Kind of what I meant

Comment: @return Perhaps you should clarify that in your OP then. Still, if the OP of a meta post thinks it would be useful, then I think the OP should either flag or post a comment asking for a screenshot (if it hasn't happened already).  I've done that multiple times.

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk then ask those who asked the question to include the relevant information. Making anything that is deleted visible to all, kind of defeats the whole deletion idea....

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk The point is: They're *deleted*. Giving anyone other than 10k users the ability to see it defeats the purpose.. This is one of those things where you just have to either ask for a screenshot or let it go.